# using the values returned by SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a little script in `python` where I use `SQLachemy` to connect to `SQLite`. I can execute selects perfectly but I don't know how to use the returned values.

I am trying to extract values with:

```
SelectQuery = self.Catalogo.select().where(self.Catalogo.c.SubcampoId == SubcampoId)

result = SelectQuery.execute()

extractedValue = result[0]
```

but it is not working.

**How can I extract values from a Query with multiple columns and use it?**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get things working?

Comment: @ConfusedByCode i published the answer, thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: No problem. You can close the question by clicking the check mark next to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finded the solution,

I only changed the code to:

```
SelectQuery = self.Catalogo.select().where(self.Catalogo.c.SubcampoId == SubcampoId)

result = SelectQuery.execute()

for row in result:
  value = row['Value']
```

now i can use the value for different operations.

Thanks.